# Backspace not working as expected on Alacritty

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, zsh

I just installed [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) through the app store on top of zsh and oh-my-zsh, I had it before on a previous installation of Ubuntu without any zsh related stuff where everything was fine.

The backspace key doesn't show any character being deleted when I type in Alacritty, but the effect is there. Instead, it ends up adding more space only visually.

Earlier it was giving me a warning "... terminal is not fully functional", which I'm not entirely sure how I got rid of. Also tab completions are weird and don't show as expected.

When I use the terminal that came with Ubuntu the backspace key works fine. I looked around online and couldn't find anything, I don't even know what to search for.

Any help would be appreciated. I am a beginner to intermediate Linux user.

=== **EDIT** ===

All movement and typing is strange.

=== **EDIT 2** ===

[This](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/2838#issuecomment-537414944) seems to have shed some light on the issue but I'm not sure why this works or what's the lesson here.